# Define Thumbnail in iOS Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

if you are receiving a local or push notification on iOS 15, normally you see the app's icon on the left of the notification and have the ability to attach media that is shown as thumbnail on the right. See here:

[image: Notifcations]

However some notifications (communications apps?) show the profile picture of the person sending the message (eg. iMessage or Slack in the example).

I'm running a news app and would like to place the logo of the publisher there. Is it possible to manipulate the image on the left and if so, how?

Comment: did you found solution bro?

Comment: This can be achieved by implementing Communication Notifications with a Notification Service extension. And for your use case, it might not be the right approach. I suggest that you show the logo of the publisher as an attachment instead of showing your notifications as communication notifications.

Comment: I assume the extension suggested by @SleepNot is the only way to archive this up to iOS 15, which is a bit of a hack and might get rejected by App Review. I have not found another solution.